# Perl variable expansion in Perl m//

Tags: regular-expression, perl

How does Perl do variable expansion in the `m//` match operator? What I have read is that `m//` only does variable expansion/interpolation once. But then why do I get `Unmatched ( in regex` when `$pat` is expanded ?

```
my $pat = '(\\)';
'\\' =~ /(\\)/  ? print "OK\n" : print "NO MATCH!\n";   # OK
'\\' =~ /$pat/  ? print "OK\n" : print "NO MATCH!\n";   # Unmatched ( in regex

my $pat2 = '(\\\)';
'\\' =~ /$pat2/  ? print "OK\n" : print "NO MATCH!\n";  # OK
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you've misapplied or misremembered the arcane rules around backslashes.

In a [single-quoted string literal](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#q%2f_STRING_%2f),

> A backslash represents a backslash unless followed by the delimiter or another backslash, in which case the delimiter or backslash is interpolated.

So the value of `$pat` is the three-character string `(\)`, because the backslash in the source code is followed by another backslash and this stands for a single backslash. The value of `$pat2` is the four-character string `(\\)`, because the first two backslashes in the source code stand for one backslash, and the third backslash is followed by `)` so it's left alone to be a second backslash in the string.

In a [regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters), a backslash quotes the next character unless it's alphanumeric. `/$pat/` is equivalent to `/(\)/`, which is open-group followed by a literal close parenthesis, and the `)` to close the group is missing. `/$pat2/` is equivalent to `/(\\)/` which is open-group, backslash, close-group.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign to `$pat`, the first backslash escapes the second, so the resulting string only contains one backslash. When the regex is processed, this then  escapes the closing parenthesis, leaving no un-escaped parenthesis to close the capturing group.

That is to say, `m//` only interprets the backslashes once, but they're also interpreted within `'...'`, so in total they're processed twice.

```
$ cat p.pl 
$pat = '(\\)'; print $pat
$ perl -l p.pl 
(\)
```

From the [manual](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

> Quote-Like Operators
>   `q/STRING/`
>   `'STRING'`
>   A single-quoted, literal string. A backslash represents a backslash unless followed by the delimiter or another backslash, in which case the delimiter or backslash is interpolated.

(Of course, this is different from how backslashes and single-quotes work in the shell.)